# Is it possible to remove animals from a Minecraft map?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I recently opened a map which I thought was broken, because I could not load it anymore. I increased the memory for the Java VM to 8GB and now I can open it but it is impossible to play on this map, because there are thousands of cows! I think this is why the map could not be opened with 768 MB of memory for Java.

So my question is, if there is any tool with which I can remove those cows. I've heard of several tools to manipulate the landscape, your spawn point, etc. But I don't know if there are tools that let you remove and place animals without having the map opened. When I open the world I have like one frame every 5 seconds...

Can you recommend a tool with which I can remove animals or other entities from a Minecraft world?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are running Minecraft 1.6.2 with current MCedit 0.1.7 you can use MCedit, select all (<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>a</kbd>) and delete entities. be warned this will delete ALL mobs and dropped items.

Comment: It is a world from Beta 1.5 so this should work?

Comment: As long as you haven't converted it to Anvil, it should work. The latest version of MCEdit will currently only work with the Region format.

Comment: I have converted it to Anvil since I tried to open it today. I restored the level.bak and will try to edit it now.

Comment: Ok I could remove all cows (~10k of cows in one chunk), but the world still lags heavily... I guess there are some chunks seriously broken. My other worlds work perfectly.

Comment: not a problem, cant wait for updated MCedit