# How can I despawn mobs in Minecraft 1.3.2?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I griefed my sister's creative world by making a really big lag zone. I spawned a bunch of NPCs using dispensers and eggs. Our PC is really bad so I couldn't go close enough to kill them in any way, lava, diamond sword, or TNT. The lag zone is so bad that we couldn't use a TNT cannon.

In addition, our dad doesn't allow us to download mods so don't mention downloading single player commands and do `/killall`.

Please note that they are NPC villagers that are causing a lag zone.

Comment: Related, possibly duplicate: [Is it possible to remove animals from a Minecraft map?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/53962/is-it-possible-to-remove-animals-from-a-minecraft-map)

Comment: Also: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/50456/how-can-i-de-spawn-mobs-in-minecraft-multiplayer and http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/21541/how-can-i-butcher-animals-en-masse/

Comment: Have you tried walking out of the loaded chunk zone and letting all the NPCs despawn? What kind of NPCs are they? Animals, testificates, or monsters?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How Can I Butcher Animals en Masse?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/21541/how-can-i-butcher-animals-en-masse) (on the principle that questions talking about what was the current version of Minecraft when they were asked should be assumed to continue to reference the current version of Minecraft)

Answer (score 6):

You could use [McEdit](http://www.minecraftforum.net/topic/13807-mcedit-minecraft-world-editor-now-open-source/) to load your map and clean the world from those animals. This is not a mod but a tool that run outside the game so uninstall it after the work's done. Juste make sure you're not running the game while editing the world.

You could add lava where you think those animals are and put you in a safe place while watching them burns. When they're all dead, save the map, go in McEdit and remove the lava :D

**Make a backup of your files before editing the map !**

Comment: MCEdit has a handy "remove entities from selection" filter which gets rid of all mobs without the need of lava. On the other hand, lava is awesome. Go lava! :D

Answer (score 2):

There are many ways to do this. You could do one of the following:

- Go to the top of the world and see if it still lags

  - If it does not, you could go at least a chunk away, then make a tower to the top of the world and connect it to the place where all the mobs are. Then, choose one of the following:

    - Place lava source blocks, and let them all burn (note that it might leave random lava spots when you are done)
    - Put lots of TNT and let it rain hell (This may cause Minecraft to run out of memory or your computer to freeze for a few minutes as minecraft processes this).
  - If it does, you are best off making a complex high TNT cannon somewhere where it does not lag and see if it works.

Worst comes to worst, you are going to have to delete and start over again (assuming that you could recreate everything you need).

Best of luck!